# Magento2: Issue with listing product

Tags: magento2

I've set limit display product 24/each page.

Every time when I try open page, then display all products.

https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/accessories-men.html

Any solution?

Comment: Where did you select this options?

Comment: In configuration --> Catalog

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it from Admin :

```
Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Catalog Tab >> Catalog >> Storefront >> Products per Page on List Default Value
```

Here you can add default limit value to show products in Category Listing page.

Comment: Saurabh, I have set this limi 24 products per page and still display all products.

Comment: Did you run the command from Magento root :  php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Yes, I have found issue. After install this module I have this issues: https://marketplace.magento.com/tatvic-enhancedecommerce.html Now I disable this module and all works ok.